# Configuration of Static IP Address on Windows Server 2008 for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, configuration, windows-server-2008-r2, static-ip-address

I have a system with Windows server 2008 installed on it. I have deployed a ASP.NET web application on this system after configuration of IIS. This application is running fine and users are able to access on LAN.   Now, i want it to make a server so that it can be accessible on Internet. I got Static IP address from my network provider. How should i configure this Static IP address on system having windows server 2008 ??

Waiting for reply ASAP.  Thanks to all.

Comment: HTTP requests on the public static IP hit port 80 on your internet facing router/firewall; forward that port (80) to the internal private address of the IIS machine